# migrating from mysql to postgresql for sonarqube

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sonarqube

we are using opensource sonarqube where we have mysql(5.6.27) on db.m4.large RDS Instance and sonar with 6.7.1 version. so far we have no issue until AWS announce that they are going to stop supporting mysql-5.6.27 so we planned to migrate it but before that as per documents - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements  we came to notice that mysql is not recommended for large instance. so we are looking for migrating to postgresql , is there any process that we can follow to migrate the db or any one face this issue before any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks 
Surya

Comment: There are two articles in the Postgres wiki, that might help you: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_proper_migration_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL

Comment: I already migrate from mysql to postgres, with a java program I wrote. There is no foreikn key in sonarqube schema, so you can read and write table one by one, with no order. Start with sequences, next with data. I use java and jdbc because of the easy  use of class for columns type: specialy for binary type! :)

Comment: Would you be willing to post a link to your migration program you wrote?